# pass variable from controller to template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

adminController.php

```
<?php

class AdminController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.admin';

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->layout->title = 'admin title';
        $this->layout->menu_active = 'register';
        $this->layout->content = View::make('pages.admin.register');
    }
}
```

layout/admin.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    @include('includes.head')

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row">
        @include('includes.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">

            @yield('content')

    </div>

    <footer class="row">
        @include('includes.footer')
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

includes/head.blade.php

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Scotch">

 <title>@yield('title', 'default title')</title>

<!-- load bootstrap from a cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

question is

1. how do i get `admin title` on @yield rather then `default title` that i set on the controller?
2. how can i use the $this->layout->variable to pass variables in templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get default title on @yield rather then admin title that i
>   set on the controller?

In your `register` method you are setting the `title` using following line

```
$this->layout->title = 'admin title';
```

You should use `{{ $title or 'Default Title' }}` in your `view`. Here, `or` used to print the default value when the given variable is undefined.

> How can I use the $this->layout->variable to pass variables in
>   templates?

The way you are setting the variables right now, for example:

```
$this->layout->variable = 'value';
```